# If $f(x)$ is continuous, determine if the following statement is true.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given $f(x)$ is continuous, if $f(6) > 4$ and $f(2) < - 16$, there will be a number $a$ between $1$ and $3$ such that $f(a) = - 5$.

How would you determine if this statement is true or not? What theorem would you use to prove this false or true?

Comment: This is not always true, I think

Comment: Intermediate values theorem. Make a picture to convince yourself. However, the "between 1 and 3" part is wrong.

Comment: $f(x)=\begin{cases}-17,&x\le 5\\-17+100(x-5),&x>5\end{cases}$

Comment: If I was at my house at 2 o'clock and at the store at 6 o'clock does that necessarily mean that sometime between 1 o'clock and 3 o'clock I was on the road?  No.  I could have waited to leave the house to go to the store until 4.

Answer (score 1):

Only one counter-example is enough to prove it false. There can be infinitely many such examples. I am sharing one of them:

[image]